# Invoke functions with different arguments base on object key

Tags: typescript, types

So I have the following snippet

```
interface base {
    name: string;
}
interface base2 {
    title: string;
}

const func1 = (arg: base) => {
    return arg.name;
}

const func2 = (arg: base2) => {
    return arg.title;
}

const formatter: Record<string, (arg: base | base2) => string> = {
    format: func1,
    format2: func2
}

formatter["format"]({ name: "test" });
```

The two functions have different argument types and I am trying to invoke them as a result of the return value of the object.

But I am getting a type error on the functions

Is there a way to abstractly call the functions and not produce type errors

Comment: Your annotation of `formatter` is incorrect, and if you remove that and let the compiler infer its type, [everything works](https://tsplay.dev/WYREvw).  Presumably that's not sufficient for your needs, because you want to "abstractly" call the functions, but I'm not sure what that means. Could you provide a [mre] that actually demonstrates the issue?  Or is it really as simple as "don't annotate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(arg: base | base2) => string` is a function that can handle both a `base` and a `base2` argument. `func1` and `func2` can't do this, they can handle either `base` or `base2`, so a call `formatter["format"]({ title: "test" });` is valid, but will cause `func1` to misbehave (in this case return `undefined` when it should return `string`)

You probably want a union of functions `((arg: base2) => string) | ((arg: base) => string)`. This will let you assign `func1` or `func2` to the properties of `formatter` but since an arbitrary key can be either function (and TS doesn't know which one) you can't call `formatter["format"]`  with either `base` or `base2`, you need to call with something that would be valid for either function signature, so the argument would have to be the intersection `base & base2`:

```
const formatter: Record<string, ((arg: base2) => string) | ((arg: base) => string)> = {
    format: func1,
    format2: func2
}

formatter["format"]({ name: "test" });// Not ok, what if format is (arg: base2) => string)
formatter["format"]({ title: "test" });// Not ok, what if format is (arg: base) => string)
formatter["format"]({ title: "test", name: "" });// Ok, either function will get what it needs
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEZwM4oN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcuAvrqJLIiulgEzJ5CyMMDAAbClRr0mrXAgD2IashgBXEAgCMyALzIAFHCh1KPCAEo9APgH5CUCGDVQQyY3QB0xMrNzylFXVNfn0jEzNMCF4rXVtBBycXNw9PEXEIPwDlMFUFKBI4MA5KACUIRSgAEwAealoQOgAaQ3DTNCiYmykGuisAH1aPSKxY23r6C1t9BIIYfMKwSmDtJvs5haLeZY0EXhZ-eYKijgBtACIjxfOAXQNsIlJJc8hqc+RmCwYAem-kADkFLkFABrFoAdwAFkVkMAYHljrlgBhDMMOnwxj1JrgridoBdcWBbvdhKIJJQXhA3h8vr8AUDkKCIdCkfDCbCUW0RpZuhNGhYcZtivjLkLiQ90uTkJS3i0fM93p8fn8APJg5AQUSQ6CqXYiJTIcHAMRiZB0JyGlmw3IgCAQKoYIA)

Now this is probably not what you want. If the keys are known and you are using the type annotation just to constrain that all properties have one of the known function signatures, you could use the `satisfies` operator in typescript 4.8 instead. This will check that the object respects the object type while preserving the actual property types:

```
const formatter = {
    format: func1,
    format2: func2
} satisfies Record<string, ((arg: base2) => string) | ((arg: base) => string)> 

formatter["format"]({ name: "test" });// Ok, actual type is known
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEZwM4oN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcuAvrqJLIiulgEzJ5CyMMDAAbClRr0mrXAgD2IashgBXEAgCMyALzIAFHCh1KPCAEo9APgH5CUCGDVQQyY3QB0xMrNzylFXVNfn0jEzNMCF4rXVtBBycXNw9PEXEIPwDlMFUFKBI4MA49OyEYfMKwSmDtABp7AgqCot4ajQReFioi4AwYYAgMZAAlCEUoABMAHmpaEDo6w3DTNCiYmyl5uisAH2WPSKxY2zn6C1t-ZqqOAG0AImui+4BdA2wiUkl7yGp75GYFgYAHpgcgAPIAayWiGccDEwgAngAHFB9ZCQkAKADuIFwQA)

Or if you are not using a version that supports `satisfies` yet you can use a function to do a similar constraint: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEZwM4oN4ChkHIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDcuAvrqJLIiulgEzJ5CyMMDAAbClRr0mrXAgD2IashgBXEAgCMyALzIAFHCh1KPCAEo9APgH5CUCGDVQQyY3QB0xMrNzylFXVNfn0jEzNMCF4rXVtBBycXNw9PEXEIP2CEESVkEjgAawgAMQUoArAODAAeABVkCAAPSBAAEwxkACUIRSg2mupaEDoAGkNw0zQomJspYborAB8Jj0isWNsh+gtrawMFSjqLBMdnV2QFP0VlMFVyyo49fKLSh7gq6AwDBIIYd7AlGyWlG9j+AN4QI0CF4LAs-n+FQ+HAA2gAiRGVNEAXR+RFIkjRkGoaOQzAsDAA9JTkAB5QrjRDOOBiYQATwADihgJ1CiAFAB3EC4IA)